# JQuery: append and appendTo doesn't work?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$("body").append("<p>Hi</p>");

$("<p>Hello</p>").appendTo("body");
```

```html
<body>
  <p></p>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong? append and appendTo doesn't work.
Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/Meadew

Comment: include jquery script

Comment: You just need to load jquery in your page

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one it works perfectly!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("body").append("<p>Hi append</p>");
  $("<p>Hello appendTo</p>").appendTo("body");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```